# How can Mongoid embedded_in macro get the parent document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, relationship

I'm stuck figuring out a very basic functionality that Mongoid provides; that is, the ability to reference the parent document from an embedded document. If I get it right, of course for embedded documents the parent document ID is not stored in the child document. One would think then that you can't retrieve children from parents, but not vice-versa. How can embedded_in provide such functionality? Am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I misunderstood how queries work in MongoDB. One cannot fetch embedded documents by querying for their id globally, but only as a embedded field of the parent document. I think this explains why Mongoid can retrieve the parent.